# What information I need to add to get the bug noticed?

Tags: 12.10, gedit, bug-reporting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

I filled the bug to Launchpad about Gedit.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gedit/+bug/1067915

What information I need to add, maybe some tests. Maybe I need to fill the bug to upstream?

The bug is not critical, but I want to know also how to make sure that any my reported bug will not hung without activity for many months, or even years. Because, there are such examples...